# Why can't I get a Vagrant box up with ubuntu/wily64? (Networking issue)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10

When I try to make a Vagrant instance with the `ubuntu/wily64` box, it hangs when I try to `vagrant ssh` or `vagrant provision` (it was working fine with older versions of Ubuntu). I'm pretty sure that I'm having a [common issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6683), due to a [change in Wily's networking](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). I've had some success in making the changes suggested in [this post](https://gist.github.com/brbsix/b70413dec907906ef659).

*(I'm using Vagrant 1.8 and Vbox 5.0.10)*

**What I’ve done:**

Created a Vagrant box and then modified the /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg files as as mentioned in the second part of [that post](https://gist.github.com/brbsix/b70413dec907906ef659#to-configure-the-new-interfaces):

> First, determine the name(s) of the new interface(s). You may run
>   ifconfig -a or check dmesg (i.e. dmesg | grep renamed) for a line like
>   this:
>
> [2.671805] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: renamed from eth0
>
> In this example, the new interface name is enp0s3.
>
> Once you have determined the new interface name(s), go to
>   /etc/network/interfaces.d. There should be a file named eth0.cfg with
>   the following contents:
>
> # The primary network interface
>   auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> Now copy eth0.cfg to enp0s3.cfg (or whatever the name of your interface
>   is). Edit the new file and replace all use of eth0 with enp0s3. Do
>   this for each interface you need configured. Remove eth0.cfg when you
>   are finished.
>
> Finally, restart networking with sudo systemctl restart
>   networking.service.

I've tried two options: Modify *only* the `eth0` interface, and then modify both the `eth1` and the `eth0` interfaces (see Note #1 below). When I modify only `eth0`, I can then `vagrant ssh`, but can’t `vagrant halt` then `vagrant up` without getting a timeout. Alternatively, when I modify *both* `eth0` and `eth1` vagrant up will get past the ssh timeout, but then I see this behavior (see Note #2 below):

```
$ vagrant halt wharf
$ vagrant up wharf

[ ... ]
==> wharf: Restarted DNS Service
==> wharf: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ip addr flush dev eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

*Note #1: The `eth1` interface is not created when doing a `vagrant up` from a bare `vagrant init`. This seems to be created because I'm using private networking)

Note #2: I am creating a file for the renamed `eth1`, because none exists*

**Question: Given the steps that I've taken, and the info in that post, what can I do next to debug this issue?**

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  config.dns.tld = "dev"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/wily64"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

  config.vm.define "wharf" do |wharf|
    wharf.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    wharf.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
    wharf.vm.synced_folder ".", "/opt/wharf", create: true
    wharf.vm.hostname = "wharf"
    wharf.dns.patterns = [/^wharf.dev$/, /^shipyard.dev$/, /^.*demo.dev$/]

    wharf.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    end
    wharf.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "deploy/vagrant_site.yml"
        ansible.inventory_path = "deploy/hosts/vagrant/inventory"
        ansible.sudo = true
        ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "wharfhouse" do |wharfhouse|
    wharfhouse.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.20"
    wharfhouse.vm.hostname = "wharfhouse"

    wharfhouse.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    end
    wharfhouse.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "deploy/site.yml"
        ansible.inventory_path = "deploy/hosts/vagrant/inventory"
        ansible.sudo = true
        ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There are some proposed solutions here (which have worked for several people): https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6683#issuecomment-165845564